# How to add new usercontrol to iis websites by installing exe file

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, exe, setup-deployment

I want to add a usercontrol(new feature) to my clients websites, All my websites are in same folder structure. So i have to create a installation setup to update existing websites hosted in iis.

is that possible?

Problems i'am facing: how to list all iis  websites in droupdown of Setup deployment steps,

is there any good reference for setup and deployment  in visual studio?
all responses are appreciated

Comment: You want to push one update to many servers at once?

Comment: no gave exe to every site owner to do their update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all list of website hosted on local machine see this article http://cstruter.com/blog/306

After getting the path and name I think there will be no further problem as you can just replace the file with current files.

Answer (score 0):

To access sites info from an .exe you'll want to tie into the administration API:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

This would let you loop through all the sites:

```
ServerManager mgr = new ServerManager();

    //Sites
    foreach(Site s in mgr.Sites)
    {
        //Applications
        foreach(Application app in s.Applications)
        {
            //Virtual Directories
            foreach(VirtualDirectory virtDir in app.VirtualDirectories)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

It's not really an .exe but you may want to also look into WebDeploy.

You'll first need to configure your servers: 
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy

After that setting up the different deploy configurations in visual studio is pretty easy: http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/how-to-publish-a-web-application-using-webmatrix

In the end you get two click deployments